# How to add certain values from one column to another?

Tags: r

I have a column with values "Yes" and "No". I want to place all of the "No" values into another column. How can I do that?

Example:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| No | Apples |
| No | Oranges |
| No | Bananas |
| Yes | Apples |
| Yes | Peaches |

I want:

| Column2 |
| --- |
| No |
| No |
| Apples |
| Oranges |
| Bananas |
| Apples |
| Peaches |

Just the "No"s and none of the "Yes" to be places into column2.
No idea why my table looks weird when I publish the question/

Comment: Please provide an example of your data and what you want the final dataframe to have as an end result. Are you saying you want the cells of the second column to have a no and the others to have NA?

Comment: Does your new column already exist? What is your data frame called and what are your columns called?

Comment: I added my example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Column2 = ifelse(Column1 == "No", "No", Column2))
```

We could use `mutate` with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(col1 = rep(c("yes", "no"),5)) %>% 
  mutate(col2 = ifelse(col1=="no", "no", NA_character_))
```

```
   col1 col2
1   yes <NA>
2    no   no
3   yes <NA>
4    no   no
5   yes <NA>
6    no   no
7   yes <NA>
8    no   no
9   yes <NA>
10   no   no
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I add those values to an existing column? I re-did my example.

Comment: Please see my update.